# Background width not showing 100%

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

All of a sudden the "full left secondary-bg" background div on this page: http://goo.gl/OU4MkW is not going to the full width of the screen, and I cannot understand why. It's a WordPress based site built on skeleton framework. Here's the php for the body area of the page:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <?php if (!is_page_template('onecolumn-page.php')) { ?>
                <?php if (is_front_page() && !get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hidetitle', true)) { ?>

                    <div class="full left secondary-bg">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="sixteen columns alpha">
                                        <div class="eight columns alpha hp">
                                            <?php the_content()?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="seven columns offset-by-one omega">
                                            <div class="post-area">
                                                <h2><?php the_field('featured_art_title'); ?></h2>
                                                <div class="featured-post-wrap">
                                                    <img src="<?php the_field('featured_art_image'); ?>" alt="Featured Art Post" />
                                                </div>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <?php the_field('featured_art_description'); ?> <a href="<?php the_field ('view_all'); ?>">View More</a>
                                                    </p>

                                             </div>
                                         </div>
                               </div>
                          </div><!-- container -->
                      </div>

                <?php } elseif (!get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hidetitle', true)) { ?>

                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                <?php } else {
                    echo '<br />';
                } ?>
            <?php } ?>

                <!--<div class="full left">

                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'skeleton' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'skeleton' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </div> .entry-content -->

            <?php comments_template( '', false ); ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Appears to be working fine - Chrome/Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change skeleton.css, please change the following line in css add width line

```
.column, .columns                          
 { float: left; display: inline; 
 /*margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;*/
 /* add width to 100% */
 width: 100%;
}
```